# Correct aspect ratio in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, aspect-ratio

I'm developing an application that is painting the camera on a `SurfaceView`. At the beginning I found trouble with the views. They were not correctly shown. So I used the following method to correct the aspect ratio problem:

NOTE: This method is found in several places as the one to correct aspect ratio for Android camera.

```
private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio;

    // Check wheter is portrait or landscape
    if (orientation == 1)
        targetRatio = (double) h / w;
    else
        targetRatio = (double) w / h;

    if (sizes == null)
        return null;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

This worked perfect, and my camera was shown correctly. But I found problems in newer devices, such as the LG G3. It had a resolution that this method considered that was the most appropiate one, but it was showing the image with **pillar boxes** on portrait mode, like the image show below:

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I solve this pillar box on portrait mode?

Comment: You may choose to crop the image instead of showing the black margins.

Comment: How can achieve that? That would be one of my solutions. First one, crop image. Second one, try to fit it in the space I have considering width.

Comment: The reliable way to crop preview involves using [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is a bug in that code, you are getting the 'best' result possible.

The aspect ratio of the phone's camera is not guaranteed to match that of the phone's screen.

It is just a matter of deciding what the criteria are for the best result. That code is Google's suggestion for deciding what is the best camera resolution for displaying on the phone's screen.

You might not agree with Google. In that case you will need to write your own algorithm for deciding what is the best camera resolution. You might optimize for aspect-ratio, or for the resolution along the width or height. You may try to fit the screen, or you could clip bits of the image to fill the entire screen. It's up to you.

Note: the code you posted tries to find a camera resolution that is within 10% of the screen's aspect-ratio *and* has a height that matches the screen's the closest. 
If there is no camera resolution within 10% from the screen aspect-ratio, then it picks the camera resolution that has a height that matches the screen's the closest. In this case you would have significant black bars around the pillar box.

Comment: Your answer drove me to the solution. I adjusted it using width and height and now it works how I want!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had other views in the same activity, so I wanted to fix the dimensions of the camera preview layout on the first place. In the layout you need to give the max desired dimensions (weights).

I created another method which determines the optimal preview size for any camera given the target view current width and height and also the activity orientation:

```
public static Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> cameraPreviewSizes, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, boolean isActivityPortrait) {
    if (CommonUtils.isEmpty(cameraPreviewSizes)) {
        return null;
    }

    int optimalHeight = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int optimalWidth = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (Camera.Size cameraPreviewSize : cameraPreviewSizes) {
        boolean isCameraPreviewHeightBigger = cameraPreviewSize.height > cameraPreviewSize.width;
        int actualCameraWidth = cameraPreviewSize.width;
        int actualCameraHeight = cameraPreviewSize.height;

        if (isActivityPortrait) {
            if (!isCameraPreviewHeightBigger) {
                int temp = cameraPreviewSize.width;
                actualCameraWidth = cameraPreviewSize.height;
                actualCameraHeight = temp;
            }
        } else {
            if (isCameraPreviewHeightBigger) {
                int temp = cameraPreviewSize.width;
                actualCameraWidth = cameraPreviewSize.height;
                actualCameraHeight = temp;
            }
        }

        if (actualCameraWidth > targetWidth || actualCameraHeight > targetHeight) {
            // finds only smaller preview sizes than target size
            continue;
        }

        if (actualCameraWidth > optimalWidth && actualCameraHeight > optimalHeight) {
            // finds only better sizes
            optimalWidth = actualCameraWidth;
            optimalHeight = actualCameraHeight;
        }
    }

    Size optimalSize = null;

    if (optimalHeight != Integer.MIN_VALUE && optimalWidth != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        optimalSize = new Size(optimalWidth, optimalHeight);
    }

    return optimalSize;
}
```

This uses a custom Size object, because Android's [Size](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/util/Size.html) is available after API 21.

```
public class Size {

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Size(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

}
```

You can determine the width and height of a view by listening to its global layout changes and then you can set the new dimensions. This also shows how to programmatically determine activity's orientation:

```
cameraPreviewLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // gets called after layout has been done but before display.
                cameraPreviewLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                boolean isActivityPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                Size optimalCameraPreviewSize = CustomUtils.getOptimalPreviewSize(cameraPreview.getCameraSizes(), cameraPreviewLayout.getWidth(), cameraPreviewLayout.getHeight(), isActivityPortrait);
                if (optimalCameraPreviewSize != null) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams cameraPreviewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(optimalCameraPreviewSize.getWidth(), optimalCameraPreviewSize.getHeight());
                    cameraPreviewLayout.setLayoutParams(cameraPreviewLayoutParams);
                }
            }
        });
```

You need to also rotate the camera orientation which is another issue.